# Should every react component have it's own stylesheet?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I just started with React and have a simple question I couldn't find anywhere.

So, should every React component have it's own stylesheet?

For example if I have my main App component which I render to the browser should I just include a css file there and have all my styles in that or is it bettet to have an own css file for every component?

Thanks.

Comment: Coming from someone who knows little about React, I would think that having a style-sheet for every component is cumbersome and may increase loading times for the application, unless they are all minified/concatenated together in the end. The point of a "common" style-sheet is to be able to reuse rules across various elements within the DOM.

Comment: Go for one `.css` file per `.js` file. You want your components to have control over how they are displayed.

Comment: It won't slow my web app down?

Answer (score 9):

CSS best practices in React are still heavily debated. There are pros and cons to each variation.

What you are probably looking for is modularity in your CSS. While having unique style sheets for your components does accomplish this to some degree I suggest taking a look at [CSS modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules). Packages like this can keep your CSS contained to a specific component so you don't over-write styles on other components.

Personally, I've done a little bit of both. I use a base style sheet (bootstrap for example). Then I use CSS-modules to help me make components that are unique that I might want to easily port over to other projects.

Comment: Okay. If I have an own css file for every component does that make my web app slower?

Comment: Depends. Having a CSS file for each component allows you to dynamically include/exclude CSS so you could potentially speed up your App by not loading useless CSS. Furthermore you can design your webpack to compile and minify your CSS into one file anyways. Create React App for example does this for you.

Comment: I'm using create-react-app now, does it compile every css file into one file?

Comment: it does when you build the final production application. However, if you are using the development version (by using yarn start) then it keeps the CSS files split so it can automatically update when you save. Pretty cool right?

Comment: Yeah it's nice!